# How can I auto-indent double bracket notation using Atom, in my HTML files?

Tags: atom-editor, liquid, meteor-blaze, spacebars

In my Atom editor, I have a simple shortcut on the keymap:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-a': 'editor:auto-indent'
```

In my `*.html` files, it does not indent Blaze liquid-like tags, for example:

```
{{#if something}}
{{else}}
{{/if}}
```

I looked into [Atom beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify), but it does not consider the double bracket notation. The beautifier currently attached to `*.html` is JS beautify. I tried to switch to pretty diff but, while it worked, it also corrupted the i18n helper nested in attributes, eg. `title="{{_ "edit"}}"` becomes `title="{{_ " edit"}}"="edit"}}""`

I installed the [HTML beautifier](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier) gem as suggested in the Atom beautify readme but it does not appear in the list of available beautifiers for HTML in the settings.

Any idea to point me toward the right direction and have my double bracket notation correctly indented?

Answer (score 0):

there’s a package called `‘file-types’`, which works wonderfully for changing default syntaxes. [file-types link](https://atom.io/packages/file-types)

## another solution

Select the code and head to `Edit > Lines > Auto Indent`.

To speed this up,  created a custom keyboard shortcut, enabling me to use `Ctrl + Cmd + ]` at any point. (On Windows, I would opt for `Ctrl + }` — which is `Ctrl + Shift + ]` — as `Ctrl + Alt + ]` is already taken.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use your second solution, but it does not indent properly double brackets notation. As for your first one, I can default to a spacebars syntax for HTML, but the beautifier is still the same, i.e. pretty diff. And it created the issue mentioned above with the i18n helpers.